# iOS UIButton text colour doesn't change after adding subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

I have this function which get called once a button is clicked.

I'm trying to add a view to a clicked button and a view to a un-clicked button.

This is my view's init:

```
/**
 Create the bottom border views
 */
- (void) createBottomBorderViews {
    UIButton* button = _albumsTypesButtons[0];
    //create layers
    _clickedButtonBorder = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 26, button.frame.size.width, 2)];
    _unClickedButtonBorder = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 27, button.frame.size.width, 1)];

    //set the clicked layer
    _clickedButtonBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:86/255.0 green:88/255.0 blue:87/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    //set the unclicked layer
    _unClickedButtonBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:86/255.0 green:88/255.0 blue:87/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}
```

And this is adding the views and changing the text colour according to the state of the button

```
-(void) setButtonsVisuals:(UIButton*)clickedButton {
    [_clickedButtonBorder removeFromSuperview];
    [_unClickedButtonBorder removeFromSuperview];
    for (UIButton* button in _albumsTypesButtons)
    {
        if (button == clickedButton)
        {
            button.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:225/255.0 green:112/255.0 blue:119/255.0 alpha:1.0];
            [button addSubview:_clickedButtonBorder];
        }
        else
        {
            button.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:199/255.0 green:200/255.0 blue:196/255.0 alpha:1.0];
            [button addSubview:_unClickedButtonBorder];
        }
    }
}
```

My issue:

When adding the views as sub views to the button, it doesn't change 
    the text colour...

I think it might be something with the layers or something like that, but it really don't know

Comment: How many buttons you have? Are you trying to add same view as a subview to multiple buttons?

Comment: Are you getting into the         if (button == clickedButton)
condition?

Comment: i'm adding a view to a button - it's the bottom border.
i'm getting into the condition - if i'm commetting the [button addSubView] the text colour changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was actually to use the [button setTitleColor] instead of touching it's properties.

Comment: in iOS 8 instead of `[self.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];` you must use: `[self setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`